# Unknown type name in function parameters

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header, driver

I have this header file.

```
// Bunch of constants defined first

typedef char Token[MAX_TOKEN + 1];

typedef struct
{
    Token szToken;      
    int iCategory;      
    int iSubcategory;   
    int iPrecedence;    
} Element;

typedef struct
{
    int iCount;  
    Element stackElementM[MAX_STACK_ELEM];
} StackImp;

typedef StackImp *Stack;

typedef struct
{
    int iOutCount;
    Element outM[MAX_OUT_ITEM];
} OutImp;

typedef OutImp *Out;

// Stack functions

void push(Stack stack, Element value);
Element pop(Stack stack);
int isEmpty(Stack stack);
Stack newStack();
void freeStack(Stack stack);
Element topElement(Stack stack);

void categorize(Element *pElement);
Out newOut();
void addOut(Out out, Element element);
void printOut(Out out);

int convertToPostfix(char *pszInfix, Out out); // This is confusing me...

void ErrExit(int iexitRC, char szFmt[], ...);
char * getToken(char *pszInputTxt, char szToken[], int iTokenSize);
```

This header is used by a driver which calls `int convertToPostfix(char *pszInfix, Out out)` the problem is I keeping getting `unknown type name 'Out'`as an error in my compiler. The convertToPostfix function is suppose to take a token indicate if there is any errors, and populate the out array via an addOut function(is in the driver), but I can't do anything because this error is prevent me from compiling! `convertToPostfix()` function is NOT part of the driver, it is in a separate C file if this at all matters.

Any help would be great!

EDIT: I first produce an .o file for the driver, then I do the same for the .c file that is convertToPostfix(), it is at this point

COMPILER

```
gcc -g -c -o myDriver.o myDriver.c //Complies fine.
gcc -g -c -o pretoPost.o pretoPost.c
pretoPost.c:7:38: error: unknown type name ‘Out’
 int convertToPostfix(char *pszInfix, Out out)
```

That I get the error.

EDIT 2: Big thanks to the people to helped! The error was that I didn't include the `#include "header.h"` into my pretoPost.c file!

Comment: is that the first error you get? Header seems to be missing a line just after "} Element;"

Comment: It's probably better not to `typedef` a pointer unless you use some kind of Camel or Hungarian notation to make it clear when reading the body of the code. For example `pOut`.

Comment: "separate C file". does that mean it is being compiled, too. Is the header actually being included by the file the error shows up in, because it should be.

Comment: @Garry Godfrey Woops I edited the post to have the line after Element; but Yes this is the first and only error I get so far since I can't compile further. This "separate C File" is being compiled too. It is when I try to compile it (gcc -g -c -o cs2123p1.o cs2123p1.c) that I get the error!
.@Weather Vane the header and driver where provided by my professor, I was advised not to mess with them.

Comment: Does `pretoPost.c` have `#include "mystery.h"` in it (where `"mystery.h"` is your unnamed header file)?  If not, that's the trouble. Also note that you've not defined a prototype for `newStack()` or `newOut()` in particular.  You've declared that the functions exist, but you've not specified the parameter list, so any number and any types of values are allowed. You need `Out newOut(void);` and `Stack newStack(void);` to declare a prototype for the functions. This is C, not C++ — in C++, the rules would be different. (This may just be sloppy coding by your professor if he supplied the header.)

Comment: Note that the error message is about `pretoPost.c` not understanding `Out`, not about the header not understanding `Out`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonathan Leffler! I had no idea I had to have the include file in pretoPost.c, but now that you mention it I can understand why it wasnt working! Ill keep in mind the stuff you said about 'newstack()' and 'newOut()' btw! Thank you for saving what hair I have left in my head!

Comment: @GarrGodfrey: You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments to an answer.*</sup>

<sup>*If Garr Godfrey provides an answer, please accept it — he provided the first pointer to the trouble.*</sup>

#### First pointer to the issue

[Garr Godfrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3991211/garr-godfrey) [commented]):

> "Separate C file" — does that mean it is being compiled, too? Is the header actually being included by the file the error shows up in, because it should be.

#### Extended commentary pointing to the issue

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613981/unknown-type-name-in-function-parameters?noredirect=1#comment53080451_32613981):

> Does `pretoPost.c` have `#include "mystery.h"` in it (where "`mystery.h`" is your unnamed header file)? If not, that's the trouble.

[and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613981/unknown-type-name-in-function-parameters?noredirect=1#comment53080526_32613981):

> Note that the error message is about `pretoPost.c` not understanding `Out`, not about the header not understanding `Out`.

And this seems to have been the problem!

> Also note that you've not defined a prototype for `newStack()` or `newOut()` in particular. You've declared that the functions exist, but you've not specified the parameter list, so any number and any types of values are allowed. You need `Out newOut(void);` and `Stack newStack(void);` to declare prototypes for the functions. This is C, not C++ — in C++, the rules would be different. (This may just be sloppy coding by your professor if he supplied the header.)

This is a common misunderstanding.  A function declaration such as:

```
void *somefunction();
```

simply says that `somefunction` exists and returns a `void *` value.  It has no direct specification of the type or number of the arguments, but the function can't be variadic (like `printf()`, taking a variable number of arguments) because you must *always* have a prototype in scope before you use a variadic function.  To say 'no arguments', C requires:

```
void *somefunction(void);
```

Now you have a prototype.  If you compile with GCC, consider:

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes …
```

It takes a little while to get used to the discipline this imposes, but it ensures you skip testing a lot of bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed explanation! I unfortunately can't vote for peoples responses due to not having over 15 rep, So thanks to Johnathan Garr and Weather for the responses!